# How to put current year and previous year on title - Power BI related question

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm not sure if this is possible. On my graph, I would like to add a current year or previous year (Ex: right now is 2021 and previous year is 2020), so we wouldn't have to go to the dashboard to change the year of the title every year. I'm using "current year" as the solution for now but would like to have a year automatic populated in the title.

If there is a way, would you please share with me? Thanks!

[image]